# Как избавиться от ошибки «Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Subscribers[]'»? Angular 2

Tags: angular2

Здравствуйте.
Есть json

```
{"count":"404875", "data":[{ ... }]}
```

В сервисе получаю ответ от сервера

```
getSubscribers(page:Number, pageSize:Number): Observable<Subscribers[]> {
    return this.http.get(this._subscribers +'/'+page+'/'+pageSize)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError)
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
}
```

в компоненте я пытаюсь обработать этот json

```
getSubscribers(page = 1){
    this.subscribersService.getSubscribers(page, this.pageSize)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.subscribers = data.data,
                this.count = data.count,
                this.p = page
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        )
}
```

И все работает. Данные корректно отображаются и все нормально работает, но при старте npm в консоле вылазят ошибки

> app/components/subscribers/index.component.ts(32,45): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Subscribers[]'.
>
> app/components/subscribers/index.component.ts(33,39): error TS2339: Property 'count' does not exist on type 'Subscribers[]'.

Файлы компонента и сервиса
[index.component.ts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzFbCylZ8fxCZ0hxLWdUOF95OTg)
[subscribers.service.ts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzFbCylZ8fxCNlZMWjQ2SHptajg)

Замена Observable на Promise не помогла.

Я понимаю, что здесь говорится, что у данного объекта нету этих свойств. Я недавно начал изучать angular и пока не понимаю как с этим бороться. Буду очень благодарен за подсказки либо помощь где или что я сделал не так.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: добавь в вопрос определение класса Subscribers. А хотя не надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дописав возвращаемое значение

```
: Observable<Subscribers[]>
```

Ты говоришь компилятору typescript, что получаемым значением из обсервера будет **массив** элементов типа *Subscribers*.

Таким образом `data` в callback для `subscribe` будет иметь тип `Subscribers[]`.

И при попытка получить *у массива* свойство `data`, компилятор typescript резонно говорит, что такое свойство у массива отсутствует.

---

Судя по предоставленному json, для решения проблемы нужно возвращать не массив

```
getSubscribers(page:Number, pageSize:Number): Observable<Subscribers>
```

Comment: ошибки остались.

Comment: @dima-gr, ну тогда без определения класса _Subscribers_ не обойтись. Если в нем нет поля data - то тогда его надо добавить. Либо вообще использовать какой-нибудь отдельный класс, соответствующий получаемому json

Comment: @dima-gr, ошибки на самом деле поменялись. Можешь добавить текст новых ошибок

Comment: @Grandy app/components/subscribers/index.component.ts(32,45): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Subscribers'.
[0] app/components/subscribers/index.component.ts(33,39): error TS2339: Property 'count' does not exist on type 'Subscribers'.

Comment: @dima-gr, и как я и сказал в ответе: у этого класса нет этих свойств. Нужно либо добавить их в этот класс, либо использовать свой класс. Откуда у тебя вообще этот класс _Subscribers_? Добавляй в вопрос определение этого класса

Comment: добавление свойств в класс помогло, сам класс описывает данные которые получаю с сервера, но добавление этих свойств в класс не самый правильный способ, наверное будет правильнее расширить этот класс другим и добавить эти свойства в него. Спасибо за помощь, очень помогли.

Comment: @dima-gr, если _сам класс описывает данные которые получаю с сервера_ - то почему не самый правильный способ сделать его таким, чтобы он соответствовал ответу сервера?